# What should I consider before vacuum-sealing seeds for storage?

Tags: perennials, seed-saving, annuals, storage

This year I have harvested more seeds than I will use next spring. I plan to vacuum-seal them and I want to know if, except for drying them really well, I should consider anything in particular.

These seeds were harvested from plants that belong to the following genera: Calendula, Celosia, Centaurea, Cosmos, Dianthus, Echinacea, Helianthus, Lavatera, Matricaria, Tropaeolum and Zinnia.

Comment: Can't speak for all of them, but Calendula and Nasturtium seeds I've just popped in an ordinary,  sealed letter envelope (once they were air dried), folded up and put inside a tin, and they still grew five years later

Comment: At first I thought that you collect seeds with a vacuum cleaner.

Comment: I would just put them in the plastic and vacuum seal away.  As long as they are dry they would be best preserved in a vacuum sealed bag in the freezer.  I am still on the fence about freezing or just cool, dark, stable temperatures.  Mine are all vacuum sealed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enemies of seeds are: heat, light and humidity, by controlling these you can store some seeds for many years.
Keep seeds at a cool to cold temperature of 40 degrees or less.
Avoid fluctuations in temperature such as a garage or storeroom that is cold in winter but blazing hot in summer.
Avoid light and never store seeds in direct sunlight or a well lit room.

Comment: are you sure about the light without heat?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you elaborate

Comment: Some seeds are inhibited by light.

Comment: Ok but I'm still not getting your point, you said are you sure the light without heat explain this comment from the context of my answer

Comment: Does light without any accompanying heat cause seeds to germinate?

Comment: Depends on the humidity and other factors, the heat from the light source could of course cause germination